# Individual slide delay // Superslides

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a problem with superslides from nicinabox [Github Link](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides)

I know that you can use the 'play' option in order to set a time in milliseconds before progressing to the next slide automatically. This sets a global time for the entire slideshow.

What I would like to achieve is for individual slides to have their own specific progress/delay time. 
For example if I have a slideshow with twenty slides I want all the slides to progress automatically and to stay on screen for 5 seconds. However the third slide should be displayed for 20 seconds.

I have tried to do this by using the animated.slides event but I cant get it to work as the animation stops with the fourth slide :

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
  $('#slides').superslides({

      hashchange: true,
      play: 5000,
      pagination: true
  });


});

$('#slides').on('animated.slides', function () {
  var current_index = $(this).superslides('current');

  if (current_index === 2) { // third slide

      $(this).superslides('stop');

      var disp = function test1() {

          setTimeout(function ()

              {
                  $('#slides').superslides('animate', 3)
              }, 20000);

      }
      disp();

  }

});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Maybe there is someone out there to solve my problem.

Comment: "animation stops with the fourth slide" - does the fourth slide also show for 20 seconds? If so, change your condition from 2 to 1.

Comment: thanks for you fast response but as you can see it http://jsfiddle.net/aj6RV/3/ the problem is not solved :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.superslides('animate', 3)` with `.superslides('start')`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aj6RV/5/) (the condition is 2, as you originally wrote)

Comment: Oh sry i haven't see the times so Thank you so much @trojansdestroy

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
$('#slides').on('animated.slides', function () {
  var current_index = $(this).superslides('current');

  if (current_index === 2) { // third slide

      $(this).superslides('stop');

      var disp = function test1() {

          setTimeout(function ()

              {
                  $('#slides').superslides('start')
              }, 20000);

      }
      disp();

  }

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aj6RV/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#slides').superslides({
      hashchange: true,
      play: 500,
      pagination: true
  });

$('#slides').on('animated.slides', function () {
    var slideNo = $(this).superslides('current');
    if(slideNo === 2){
        $(this).superslides('stop');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#slides').superslides('start')
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/QB4gy/).