# Video starts when current slide // Superslides

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I solved the individual slide delay problem with superslides using the answers found at [Individual slide delay // Superslides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991815/individual-slide-delay-superslides), but now I'm having trouble with a video I put in.

The video is Slide 4, but it starts playing when the slider loads. I'm using YTPlayer for the player.

```
jQuery('#fullscreen , .p-section').superslides({
    play: 12000,
    animation: 'fade',
    inherit_height_from: window,
});

jQuery('#fullscreen').on('animated.slides', function () {
var slideNo = jQuery(this).superslides('current');
if(slideNo === 3){ //slide 4
    jQuery(this).superslides('stop');
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#fullscreen').superslides('start')
    }, 20000);
} });
```

That is what I have for the slider. How can I get the video to start playing only when the video is the current slide and then transitions to the next slide after it plays.

UPDATE: IN CASE SOMEONE WAS LOOKING FOR THIS AS WELL.
With the help of @Sunand, here's what I have.

```
jQuery('#fullscreen , .p-section').superslides({
    play: 12000,
    animation: 'fade',
    inherit_height_from: window,
});

jQuery('#fullscreen').on('animated.slides', function () {
var slideNo = jQuery(this).superslides('current');
if(slideNo === 3){ //slide 4
jQuery(this).superslides('stop');
jQuery(".mb_YTVPBar .buttonBar").css({"display":"block"}); 
jQuery(".home-elements").css({"display":"none"}); 
jQuery("#bgndVideo").playYTP();

jQuery("#bgndVideo").on("YTPEnd",function(){
    jQuery('#fullscreen').superslides('start');
     jQuery(".mb_YTVPBar .buttonBar").css({"display":"none"});
     jQuery(".home-elements").css({"display":"block"});  
});
}
});
```

Now I'm still working on if they click next before the video is done, then the video should stop. Will update this when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set autoPlay:false in the data-property attribute and change ur code to

```
jQuery('#fullscreen').on('animated.slides', function () {
var slideNo = jQuery(this).superslides('current');
if(slideNo === 3){ //slide 4
    var me = this;
    jQuery(this).superslides('stop');
    jQuery("#videoID").playYTP();
    jQuery("#videoID").one("YTPEnd",function(){
        jQuery(me).superslides('start');
    });

} });
```

Comment: I had set the autoPlay to true but it started playing when the video wasn't on the current slide. And the slider didn't transition after the video was done playing.

Comment: @StephenB sorry that was my mistake. set it to false

Comment: GREAT! It's working! Do I have to add anything to make it transition to the next slide after the video is done?

Comment: @StephenB Edited my post please check

Comment: Thanks @Sunand! You are a livesaver!